# how to make template function header shorter

Tags: c++, templates

I have a template class, let's call it foo. In the implementation, I have:

```
template<class a, class b ... class x>
void foo<a, b, ..., x>::function1() { }

template<class a, class b ... class x>
void foo<a, b, ..., x>::function2() { }
```

Now I want to make it simpler to read. Could I do something like typedef to
define a THING that is

```
template<class a, class b... class x> foo<a, b, ..., x>
```

then make the above function header simpler (shorter)?

THanks!

Comment: Well, you could always put the function definitions inline in the class…

Comment: How many template parameters does it have? That seems like the main issue.

Comment: The problem is I want to separate the implementation. And there are like 6 parameters.

Comment: What I have now is a lot of duplicate codes. I have to write the long header many times.

Comment: I've used the preprocessor to help with complex template arguments before.

Comment: But _why_ do you want to separate the implementation? If it's about making things more readable, and it's having the opposite effect, don't do it.

Comment: How would you make it shorter? If it still needs to list all 6 template parameters and the class name and the function name, then I don't see what could be done. What information would you like the shorter version to hide?

Comment: @jalf: I think he's wishing C++ had a way to say `template_params<class foo> void foo<template_args<class foo>>::function1()`, because the compiler has to know that information, so why should he have to type it? That's not an unreasonable wish in general, it's just something C++11 doesn't have any way to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first question is, does your class template really need that many parameters? If so, can they be packed up in some way?

Second, if the boilerplate of defining all of the functions out-of-line is overwhelming the actual code, why not define them inline, in the class definition? Yes, some people consider that generally bad style, but it's a tradeoff—the goal of that guideline is to make your code more readable, and if it's having the opposite effect, ignore it.

Even if you want to keep the implementation in a separate `.ipp` file that gets included at the end of the `.hpp` file for better code organization, you can change that to including the `.ipp` in the middle:

foo.hpp:

```
template <class a, class b ... class x>
class foo {
  #include "foo_impl.ipp"
};
```

foo_impl.ipp:

```
void function1() {}
void function2() {}
```

If neither of those ideas appeals to you, there's no way a typedef or template alias could help, because that's for giving names to specializations of templates. No matter what you do, any template parameters that are still free, still have to be listed, or the compiler won't know what you're talking about.

But you could always use the preprocessor:

```
#define FOOMETHOD(rettype) template<class a, class b ... class x> \
                           rettype foo<a, b, ..., x>

FOOMETHOD(void)::function1() { }
FOOMETHOD(void)::function2() { }
```

There are lots of ways you could modify this—put the `::` in the macro, break it into two macros so you don't need to pass in the rettype, define a different macro for each type, etc. Whatever looks most reasonable for your use case, do that.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ you're kind of stuck here as there's no direct solution to your problem. You can either define the functions inline to avoid typing the parameters, or pack all the types into a policy class:

```
struct Policy1
{
    typedef int B;
    typedef double B;
    typedef Foo C;
};

template<class Policies>
void foo<Policies>::function1() { }

foo<Policy1> FooObject;
```

All that said, with many template parameters I highly suggest double-checking and triple-checking your design. Do *all* the parameters really have to vary independently of each other? If so you may wind up with hundreds or thousands of instantiations of your class.

Comment: He's not instantiating different things based on the template parameters, he's merely defining template class member functions.

Comment: @MooingDuck: We don't know exactly what he's using the parameters for, so it's possible that calling this a policy class is inappropriate… but even in that case, the idea would work exactly the same.